# PostgresQL keeps connecting me to my "admin username" database

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

It frustrates me that when I run "npm run migrate:test" to migrate my tables to the test database, Postgres keeps putting out error: "database  does not exist. Even though I had specified the connection as "postgresql://dunder-mifflin@localhost/imagery-api-test"

More code:

```
    before('make knex instance', () => {
        db = knex({
            client: 'pg',
            connection: "postgresql://dunder-mifflin@localhost/imagery-api-test"
        })
        app.set('db', db)
    })
```

Not sure why it keeps connecting me to a non-existent database. I have tried a few hours and couldn't figure it out. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check whats mentioned in your drivers string?

Answer (score 0):

For knex you would want to add the expiration as it caches your connection info and reuses it everytime.

By default, the configuration object received via a function is cached and reused for all connections. To change this behavior, an expirationChecker function can be returned as part of the configuration object. The expirationChecker is consulted before trying to create new connections, and in case it returns true, a new configuration object is retrieved. For example, to work with an authentication token that has a limited lifespan:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'postgres',
  connection: async () => {
    const { token, tokenExpiration } = await someCallToGetTheToken();
    return {
      host : 'your_host',
      user : 'your_database_user',
      password : token,
      database : 'myapp_test',
      expirationChecker: () => {
        return tokenExpiration <= Date.now();
      }
    };
  }
});
```

More here: [git repo](https://github.com/Vincit/knex-db-manager)

and here: [knex official](http://knexjs.org/)